# shift array item by 4 position

Tags: c++, arrays

these function only moves the elements inside my a[] 1 position to the right, but i want to move it by 4 position. i am a newbie. any hint or help with this guys?

```
void shiftright (int a[], int size);

int main (void)
{
    int a []= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    shiftright( a, 8);
    for ( int i=0; i<8; i++) 
    {
        cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
    return(0);
}

void shiftright (int a[], int size)
{
    int temp;
    int temp1;
    for (int i=0; i<(size -1); i++)
    {
        temp = a[size-1];
        a[size-1] = a[i];
        a[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

Comment: call 'shiftright' 3 more times

Comment: haha. thanks man. since i don't care my about the performance issue. that is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not a key value, you can call 'shiftright' three more times (I assume you cannot use std::rotate). Revising the 'shiftright' function to accommodate shift of 4 will make it less reusable (in most cases). For example, if next time you need to rotate only twice, you will be able to use the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach to rotate an `array` by order `k` in your case `k is 4`.

```
void reverse_array(int* arr, int left, int right) {
    int* p1 = arr + left;
    int* p2 = arr + right;
    while (p1 < p2) {
        int temp = *p1;
        *p1 = *p2;
        *p2 = temp;
        p1++;
        p2--;
    }
}

void shiftright(int* arr, int k, int size) {
    int n = size;
    reverse_array(arr, 0, n-1); //! First reverse the complete array
    reverse_array(arr, 0, k-1); //! Now reverse first k elements
    reverse_array(arr, k, n-1); //! Now reverse element from k to last
}
```

If you are writing this function just for learning purpose than it's ok otherwise as suggested use standard functions for this like `std::rotate` instead of writing your own version.